# How to plug in SqlClientFactory instance into Entity Framework 6.2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Using EF6.2, I'm getting a runtime error

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'

Here is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): https://github.com/Nomenator/Demo.AspNetCore2.EF6

When you launch it, you will get a `NotSupportedException` (I forked the code from another repo and fixed some package references/project targets).

With some google-fu, I found this interesting article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Nov/27/Working-around-the-lack-of-dynamic-DbProviderFactory-loading-in-NET-Core#the-missing-dbproviderfactories-in-westwind.globalization

So I can see how it provides an implementation of `SqlClientFactory`, but I don't understand how to make my EF configuration use said implementation or how to plug in an implementation of my own.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others, including the app.config/web.config.

Comment: @Progman thanks for pointing that out. I changed the text near my github repo to indicate that it is the MCVE. This repository contains a complete application which exhibits this problem.